# How to make this long sql query a full join?

Tags: mysql

I have the following sql query. It is used to get stats on users who only logged in once this week. My problem is that I am missing some data. When I run a simple query to see how many users only logged in once this week I get five rows but this query only returns four rows. I assume this is because the tables are only left joined. As I am creating tables in the query I am having trouble and keep getting errors when trying to add in the union statement to make it a full join. Here is the query any help appreciated.

```
SELECT a.user_id, 
   a.logins, 
   a._date, 
   COALESCE(b.loaded, 0)    loaded, 
   COALESCE(c.attempted, 0) attempted, 
   COALESCE(d.correct, 0)   correct 
FROM   (SELECT l.user_id, 
           l.in_datetime, 
           Date_format(l.in_datetime, '%d/%m/%Y') _date, 
           Count(*)                               AS logins 
    FROM   production.login l 
    GROUP  BY user_id) a 
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT user_id, 
                     Count(*) AS loaded 
              FROM   production.score s 
                     JOIN processedquestion pq 
                       ON s.attempt_id = pq.attempt_id 
              GROUP  BY user_id) b 
          ON a.user_id = b.user_id 
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT user_id, 
                     Count(*) AS attempted 
              FROM   production.score s 
                     JOIN processedquestion pq 
                       ON s.attempt_id = pq.attempt_id 
              WHERE  s.selected_answer IS NOT NULL 
              GROUP  BY user_id) c 
          ON c.user_id = b.user_id 
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT user_id, 
                     Count(*) AS correct 
              FROM   production.score s 
                     JOIN processedquestion pq 
                       ON s.attempt_id = pq.attempt_id 
              WHERE  s.selected_answer = s.correct_answer 
              GROUP  BY user_id) d 
          ON c.user_id = d.user_id 
WHERE  logins = 1 
   AND Year(a.in_datetime) = Year(Curdate()) 
   AND Week(a.in_datetime) = Week(Curdate())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the problem has anything to do with full joins. The issue is that you need to move your logins date filter into the table expression. The query above looks for users with only a single login *in the entire table* which is why you have fewer results.

Also note that your query wouldn't have run on systems that correctly disallow the return of a non-aggregate column in a grouping query. In your case you only wanted a single date so it didn't really matter; however, the correct method is to use a dummy aggregate like `min()` on the `_date` calculation. I'm calling this out because it's a source of many problems for MySQL devs.

The single login condition can also be expressed with `having` which has the benefit of keeping that part of the logic in one place without the need to expose a separate count column to reference later. I suppose that's possibly a matter of preference though I would argue it makes sense to use the tools built into the language.

I've also consolidated the multiple joins in a single table which should make it a lot simpler to follow.

```
select
    ...
from
    (
        select user_id, min(date_format(in_datetime, '%d/%m/%Y')) _date,
        from production.login
        where year(in_datetime) = year(curdate()) and week(in_datetime) = week(curdate())
        group by user_id
        having count(*) = 1
    ) users
        left outer join
    (
        select
            s.user_id, /* I qualified with s but not sure that was the right table */
            count(*) as loaded,
            count(s.selected_answer) as attempted,
            count(case when s.selected_answer = s.corrected_answer then 1 end) as correct
        from production.score s inner join processedquestion pq
            on pq.attempt_id = s.attempt_id
        group by user_id
    ) questions
        on questions.user_id = users.user_id
```

I have no idea how large your logins table is but the query might run more efficiently if you were to calculate a start and end date and use `in_datetime between <start_of_week> and <end_of_week>` rather than a check based on extracting the year and week parts. And actually I think you'll have worse problems when you use this in the first week of January.

Comment: cheers i'll check that out. I just added the statement `WHERE year(in_datetime) = year(curdate()) AND week(in_datetime) = week(curdate())` into the query for table a and got back five results

Comment: @nasoj1100 I'm glad it worked. Make sure to note my last comment about running in January.

Comment: why do you think this will have worse problems?

Comment: I meant worse concerns than just efficiency. If your week starts in December but current date is in January then you won't be looking at the full week of data.